# Security issue with Vaadin 8 and outdated HighCharts library

Tags: security, vaadin

we are receiving a lot of heat regarding a VAPT of our application which uses Vaadin 8.13.2 and Vaadin Charts 4.2.1. Vaadin charts uses High Charts 4.2.7 which has several know security issues (eg. XSS https://snyk.io/vuln/SNYK-JS-HIGHCHARTS-571995).

We do need a fix for that or at least a formal communication from Vaadin stating that in Vaadin 8 that vulnerability is not enforceable.

Vaadin sales support said to ask here for this kind of help and documentation, we are Pro Customers.

edit: they fixed the issue by better sanitizing the inputs in Vaadin Charts 4.3.0

Comment: Check the pentest, update your versions, fix the things you can prevent, and for the rest, create pull requests upstream.  And if the vendor tells you to GTFO for reporting security problems, you are either only telling half of the story here, or you should consider switching vendors.

Comment: Regarding security concerns Vaadin has official channel for reporting them, see more at: https://vaadin.com/security

Comment: This question is not related to using the Highcharts library - wrong tag used.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel I respectfully disagree, Vaadin Charts adds Java API to the Highcharts library, but it's still Highcharts. And the question is about security issues in Highcharts, so I'd say that's pretty relevant.

Comment: @AnnaKoskinen but notice that as a user of Vaadin you are able only to configure Vaadin charts (which wraps Highcharts really old version). From Highcharts perspective, nothing can be done here.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel Highcharts users may still have valuable insights to offer about the vulnerabilities and what kind of use cases might be best to be avoided if you are stuck using that version, and so forth. And we from the Vaadin team are reading these too, if anyone proposes solutions that can be only implemented within the add-on itself.

Comment: @AnnaKoskinen makes sense now, I can agree with that! :) but I am afraid that the best solution is to upgrade Highcharts to the newest version. Our dev team efforted a lot for fixing any memory leaks and security issues. Also, a lot has changed from the 4.2.7 version, and implementing some solutions might be difficult.

Comment: Just FYI: The reported vulnerability does not happen in Highcharts 4.2.7 using given example https://jsfiddle.net/alvarezg/gyev3saj/

Comment: Sanitizing fix is available in Vaadin Charts 4.3.0: https://github.com/vaadin/charts/releases/tag/4.3.0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm sad to hear that someone from Vaadin has redirected security concerns to Stack Overflow rather than forwarding the discussion to [our security team](https://vaadin.com/security). At the same time, I realize that not everyone at Vaadin is a software engineer with deep security insights and that mistakes can happen.

Our overall understanding is that the issues that are reported against [this version of Highcharts](https://snyk.io/test/npm/highcharts/4.2.7) are only applicable in case chart data or configuration is based on input from untrusted users, which is typically not the case in the types of applications that are built using Vaadin.

We will still have to take some time to double check the details before we can draw any definite conclusions. It's unfortunately not practical to follow the recommendation from Highcharts to update to a newer version because of backwards compatibility issues. It might be feasible to introduce additional checks in Vaadin Charts to mitigate these risks, or then we will have to make specific recommendations for application code.

We are also discussing whether Vaadin should be more proactive with security issues in transitive dependencies, but this is a complex question that requires balancing between many different factors.

Kind regards,
Leif Åstrand
CTO at Vaadin

Comment: Thanks @leif-Åstrand, wrote to the security support as per your suggestion.

Comment: As per edit, fixed in vaadin charts 4.3.0