# Is Vaadin using secure frontend dependencies?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin14

I'm using the latest Vaadin 14 LTS Verson (14.8.20)
Upon building my project, intellij suggested installing the npm packages from the automatically created package.json.
NPM then told me it found 12 vulnerabilities of which 11 have a high severity.
So is Vaadin using outdated packages here? Is it dangerous to use this in production?
The output of npm audit fix is:

```
up to date, audited 1276 packages in 7s

79 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

# npm audit report

ansi-html  <0.0.8
Severity: high
Uncontrolled Resource Consumption in ansi-html - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-whgm-jr23-g3j9
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install webpack-dev-server@3.11.3, which is outside the stated dependency range
node_modules/ansi-html
  webpack-dev-server  2.0.0-beta - 4.7.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of ansi-html
  Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
  Depends on vulnerable versions of selfsigned
  node_modules/webpack-dev-server

glob-parent  <5.1.2
Severity: high
glob-parent before 5.1.2 vulnerable to Regular Expression Denial of Service in enclosure regex - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-ww39-953v-wcq6
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install copy-webpack-plugin@11.0.0, which is a breaking change
node_modules/copy-webpack-plugin/node_modules/glob-parent
node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/glob-parent
node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/glob-parent
  chokidar  1.0.0-rc1 - 2.1.8
  Depends on vulnerable versions of glob-parent
  node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/chokidar
  node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar
    watchpack-chokidar2  *
    Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
    node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2
      watchpack  1.7.2 - 1.7.5
      Depends on vulnerable versions of watchpack-chokidar2
      node_modules/watchpack
  copy-webpack-plugin  5.0.1 - 5.1.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of glob-parent
  node_modules/copy-webpack-plugin

highcharts  <=8.2.2
Severity: high
Cross-Site Scripting in highcharts - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-gr4j-r575-g665
Options structure open to Cross-site Scripting if passed unfiltered - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-8j65-4pcq-xq95
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install @vaadin/vaadin-charts@23.2.7, which is a breaking change
node_modules/@vaadin/vaadin-shrinkwrap/node_modules/highcharts
node_modules/highcharts
  @vaadin/vaadin-charts  <=6.2.0-beta1 || 6.2.1 - 22.0.0-rc1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of highcharts
  node_modules/@vaadin/vaadin-charts
  node_modules/@vaadin/vaadin-shrinkwrap/node_modules/@vaadin/vaadin-charts
    @vaadin/vaadin-shrinkwrap  <=22.0.0-rc1
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @vaadin/vaadin-charts
    node_modules/@vaadin/vaadin-shrinkwrap

node-forge  <=1.2.1
Severity: high
Open Redirect in node-forge - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-8fr3-hfg3-gpgp
Prototype Pollution in node-forge debug API. - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-5rrq-pxf6-6jx5
Improper Verification of Cryptographic Signature in `node-forge` - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-2r2c-g63r-vccr
Improper Verification of Cryptographic Signature in node-forge - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-x4jg-mjrx-434g
Improper Verification of Cryptographic Signature in node-forge - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-cfm4-qjh2-4765
URL parsing in node-forge could lead to undesired behavior. - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-gf8q-jrpm-jvxq
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install webpack-dev-server@3.11.3, which is outside the stated dependency range
node_modules/node-forge
  selfsigned  1.1.1 - 1.10.14
  Depends on vulnerable versions of node-forge
  node_modules/selfsigned

12 vulnerabilities (1 moderate, 11 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
(base) jonas@scadsnb28 IdeaProjects/de4l-client (master *%) npm install                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1 ↵

up to date, audited 1276 packages in 3s

79 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

12 vulnerabilities (1 moderate, 11 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Answer (score 3):

Vaadin uses JS dependencies in two ways

- for building the web-components used by your application in the browser aka your frontend code
- for compiling these web-components and outputing an optimized and pruned bundled specific for your application, it means run a nodejs tool (webpack) that is only used for compilation.

Obviously, both are written in JS, thus their dependencies are defined in the same `package.json` file, but only the first set of dependencies affects to your application code, they are defined in the `dependencies` section, while the tools are defined in the `devDependencies` section.

You should not worry so much for the vulnerabilities during the compilation time, they are quite difficult to exploit at that point, and they don't get passed to your application front-end bundle.

So, let me remove some of the reported vulnerabilities by executting the same command but with the `--omit dev` parameter

```
$ npm audit report --omit dev

highcharts  <=8.2.2
Severity: high
Cross-Site Scripting in highcharts - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-gr4j-r575-g665
Options structure open to Cross-site Scripting if passed unfiltered - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-8j65-4pcq-xq95
...
```

As you can see, only `highcharts` is signficant, and only in the case you are using Vaadin Charts components in your application.

Let's assume you are using charts, the vulnerabilities here are only exploitable if your application exposes chart configuration based on unsanitized user inputs.

Here you have a more complete answer regarding vaadin and highcharts  [Security issue with Vaadin 8 and outdated HighCharts library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68657926/security-issue-with-vaadin-8-and-outdated-highcharts-library/68662445#68662445)

Answer (score -1):

Vaadin 23 is the latest stable version released under the new simplified release model. This is the recommended version for all users. as it is specified in their [release page](https://vaadin.com/releases)